# How to pass DataTable as Paramter tp stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created `User-Defined Table Type`s and have written stored procedure as below:

```
//Create the data type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].tbl_admintype AS TABLE 
(
    [code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [branch] [varchar](100) NULL default '',
    [location] [varchar](100) NULL default '',
    [usertype] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [password] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [saltkey] [varchar](100) NULL
)
GO

//Stored Procedure
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_tbl_admin_InsertItem]
    @tbl_admintype tbl_admintype READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO tbl_admin a
    USING @tbl_admintype at
    ON a.code=at.code and a.usertype=at.usertype
    --WHEN MATCHED THEN
        --UPDATE SET a.Name = at.Name,a.Country = at.Country
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES(at.name, at.code, at.password, at.saltkey,at.branch,at.location,at.usertype,1,getdate(),getdate());

    select ''
END
```

The following piece of code works fine:

```
using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("proc_tbl_admin_InsertItem"))
        {
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Connection = con1;                                               

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_admintype", dt);
            con1.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con1.Close();
        }
}
```

But when I used the following function:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string spName, params object[] parameterValues)
{
    try
    {

        return db.ExecuteNonQuery(spName, parameterValues);
    }
    catch (DALException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

it gives the error:

> "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 1
>   ("@tbl_admintype"), row 0, column 0: Data type 0xF3 (user-defined
>   table type) has a non-zero length database name specified.  Database
>   name is not allowed with a table-valued parameter, only schema name
>   and type name are valid.".

Comment: Not sure it is the cleaner way but you can convert DataTable to xml and parse xml using OpenXml query in sql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `AddWithValue`. Instead, do this:

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@tbl_admintype", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;
```

If you insist on using `AddWithValue` you can do it this way:

```
SqlParameter tvpParam = cmb1.Parameters.AddWithValue(
"@tbl_admintype", dt);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

This can be done since both the `Add` method and the `AddWithValue` method returns a reference to the parameter.

For more information, [read this MSDN page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i want to pass out DataTable in params object[] parameterValues

Comment: you mean you want to use a table valued parameter as an output parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `User Defined Table Type` at SQL Server to send `DataTable` from C# to stored procedure.

Just open in SSMS:

`Programmability -> Types -> UserDefined Table Types` and right click `New -> UserDefinedTableType`

Then:

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[tp_ParameterList]    
        Script Date: 18.10.2017 10:36:40 ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tp_ParameterList] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [VARCHAR](255) NULL,
    [Val] [VARCHAR](255) NULL
)
GO
```

Now you can execute your stored procedure with parameter which can accept `DataTable`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourSPWithDataTable](
     @AdditionalParams      dbo.tp_ParameterList READONLY
  )

AS
```

and you can call `stored procedure` from `C#` like that:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("YourSPWithDataTable", db.Database.Connection as SqlConnection,                                   
                 db.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Val");
dt.Rows.Add("id_Person", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("id_Dep", 1);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AdditionalParams", dt));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```